# Include post on external custom site

Tags: posts, customization, include

How do I include single post ( I mean image, title, and a bit of text ) on my own custom site?
I have wp in subdirectory and I just want to make "Recent article" box on my site.
I was looking for it 2 hours by now and nothing.

I have something like this by now, but it only shows icon of post. ( I share a lot of videos on WP so video miniature won't show) and of course it looks bad. ( I want look of my theme)

```
// The Loop
the_post();
echo '<a href="';
the_permalink();
echo '"><h4>';
the_post_thumbnail( array(180, 120) ); 
echo '<br><br>';
the_title();
echo '</h4>';
echo '</a>';
```

Comment: Do you mean you want to pull this into a non-wordpress external site?

Comment: I'm writing my own PHP website, I just want to have nice link to recent post from blog.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a plugin like [JSON API](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) to create an endpoint on your WordPress installation and access it from your PHP site with Javascript. You'll still need to style it however.